# Magento 2: About CRON readiness check issues

Tags: magento2, php, cron

In Magento 2.2.

I have this problem, but I don't have root permissions because I was using web hosting.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/trouble/readiness/tshoot_rc_cron.html

so, How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can talk to your host to follow these configurations below to run your Magento 2:

**About PHP configurations required:**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

**About Cron configurations required:**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron"